# Why does my app crash when I click items in a Fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I go to click an item in the SettingsFragment, my app crashes. Everything is displayed properly in this fragment class but only my parseUrl items work. i click on any other items and my app just closes out. Why does that happen? Below is my code.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
MainActivity context;


public SettingsFragment() {
    //public constructor
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer, container, false);


    FrameLayout instructions = view.findViewById(R.id.instructions);
    if (!getInstance().get("INSTRUCTIONS_ACTIVE", true)) {
        instructions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    instructions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            openInstructions();

        }
    });


    return view;

}

// Main functions
void openInstructions(){
    Intent transactions = new Intent(context, FragmentsActivity.class);
    transactions.putExtra("show","instructions");
    startActivity(transactions);
}


public void settingsMenu(String Type){

    switch (Type) {



        case "instructions":

            openInstructions();

            break;

}
```

Comment: So what's the error message? Please include the whole stack trace from logcat.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:130)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6082)
        at com.koupr.coinr.fragments.SettingsFragment.openTransactions(SettingsFragment.java:171)
        at com.koupr.coinr.fragments.SettingsFragment$5.onClick(SettingsFragment.java:92)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the context is null 
Use `getContext()` or `getActivity()` inside `onCreateView` to initialize the context

Comment: youre right, i checked the logcat. how would i write that?

Comment: public view onCreateView(..) {
 context = getContext();
.....
}

Answer (score 0):

context is not initialized, one way to do that is to add this method:

```
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context ctx) {
        super.onAttach(ctx);
        context = ctx;
    }
```